# Hypereldger Fabric: Bootstrap Orderer without genesis block

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I need to spin up orderer without genesis block as I don't have information about the consortium at the time of orderer bootstrap.

**Is there a way to do this?**

According to [orderer.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/sampleconfig/orderer.yaml) file, we can set `ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=none` to bootstrap orderer without genesis block. I tried that, but it doesn't work. Throws this error:

```
orderer.example.com    | 2020-05-30 16:46:03.446 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 003 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
orderer.example.com    | 2020-05-30 16:46:04.246 UTC [fsblkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 004 Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains

orderer.example.com    | panic: unable to bootstrap orderer. Error reading genesis block file: open /etc/hyperledger/fabric/genesisblock: no such file or directory
orderer.example.com    | 
orderer.example.com    | goroutine 1 [running]:
orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/bootstrap/file.(*fileBootstrapper).GenesisBlock(0xc00038e400, 0xc00038e400)
orderer.example.com    |    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/bootstrap/file/bootstrap.go:39 +0x1c0
orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.extractBootstrapBlock(0xc0001c2d80, 0xc0001249c0)
orderer.example.com    |    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:595 +0x139
orderer.example.com    | github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.Main()
orderer.example.com    |    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:128 +0x129a
orderer.example.com    | main.main()
orderer.example.com    |    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/cmd/orderer/main.go:15 +0x20
```

I tried generating a genesis block without consortium information. But it gave me a warning while generating the genesis block.  **WARN 007 Genesis block does not contain a consortiums group definition.  This block cannot be used for orderer bootstrap**

```
2020-05-30 21:26:01.892 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-05-30 21:26:01.897 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 Orderer.Addresses unset, setting to [127.0.0.1:7050]
2020-05-30 21:26:01.897 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 orderer type: etcdraft
2020-05-30 21:26:01.897 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 004 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:16777216 
2020-05-30 21:26:01.897 IST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 005 Loaded configuration: /home/nitish/work/hyperledger/research-network/configtx.yaml
2020-05-30 21:26:01.898 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 006 Generating genesis block
2020-05-30 21:26:01.898 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> WARN 007 Genesis block does not contain a consortiums group definition.  This block cannot be used for orderer bootstrap.
2020-05-30 21:26:01.898 IST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 008 Writing genesis block
```

Sample config for genesis block generation:

```
---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: ./ordererorganization/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - orderer.example.com:7050


################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V2_0 capability ensures that orderers and peers behave according
        # to v2.0 channel capabilities. Orderers and peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V2_0 orderer capability ensures that orderers behave according
        # to v2.0 orderer capabilities. Orderers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 orderer capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V2_0 application capability ensures that peers behave according
        # to v2.0 application capabilities. Peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 application capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 application capabilities, ensure that all
        # peers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft

    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ./ordererorganization/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ./ordererorganization/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
```

I know that there is someway to achieve this as I have seen some HLF Blockchain service providers spins up sample ordering service and later add a consortium to it. I couldn't find any references though. I would really appreciate any help w.r.t this. I am stuck in a deadlock.

Comment: Have you also removed the configuration 'ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE' from your orderer's peer configuration?

Comment: Yes, I removed it.

Comment: I managed to find a workaround to bootstrap orderer along with Genesis block. I am not blocked with this issue anymore. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consortium definition is required for bootstraping an orderer service. You may try defining a consortium with an empty organization list. The organization list of the consortium can be operated dynamicly.

Sample profile:

```
SampleSingleMSPSolo:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
```